# Hide Load More button on InfiniteScroll.js when hitting last page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking to hide my "Load More" button when I'm on the last page, but it seems to be refusing to hide the button when scrolling to the last page.

I am using [infinitescroll.js](https://infinite-scroll.com/)

I have the current script to [infinite scroll X pages](https://infinite-scroll.com/extras.html#scroll-2-pages-then-load-with-button), then show a load more button. Though I think this is causing conflict with checking if it's the last page. I've tried numerous ways, but I can't seem to make it work with both.

I have the following script code.

```
<script>
    let $container = $('.article-feed').infiniteScroll({
        path: '.nav-next a',
        append: '.card',
        history: 'push',
        button: '.view-more-button',
        hideNav: '.pagination',
        status: '.page-load-status'
    });

    let $viewMoreButton = $('.view-more-button');

    // get Infinite Scroll instance
    let infScroll = $container.data('infiniteScroll');

    $container.on( 'load.infiniteScroll', onPageLoad );

    $container.on( 'last.infiniteScroll', onPageLoad, function( event, body, path ) {
        console.log(`Last page hit on ${path}`);
        $viewMoreButton.attr("style", "display: none !important");
    });

    function onPageLoad() {
        if ( infScroll.loadCount == 1 ) {
            // after 2nd page loaded
            // disable loading on scroll

            $container.infiniteScroll( 'option', {
                loadOnScroll: false,
            });
            // show button
            $viewMoreButton.show();
            // remove event listener
            $container.off( 'load.infiniteScroll', onPageLoad );
        }
    }
</script>
```

Any help with this would be great. The console.log reports that it has hit the last page properly, but the button does not hide itself.

Comment: Can you create runnable code ?

Comment: This is the closest to the code above https://codepen.io/desandro/pen/PoGRaby